# Should I downvote a low quality question if it's already been closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, voting, down-votes, closed-questions

In general, if a bad question has already been closed (not necessarily for [being a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates), but, e.g., for being off-topic), and it already has a negative vote score, is it meaningful to further add your downvote?

I see no benefit to this, I only see that you lose 1 rep for adding your downvote. Can anyone explain if there’s a point to doing so?

I don’t believe this question is a perfect duplicate of “[Block downvoting a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112749/block-downvoting-a-closed-question),” because that question (which is *itself* a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem), which does not answer my question) requests making it impossible to do so whereas my question is meant to spark discussion only, leaving users with the freedom to downvote.

Comment: @rene I don't think it's a perfect duplicate. It's related, yes, but the question you linked (which is a duplicate *per se*) is a feature request, recommending to make it impossible to downvote closed questions. Whereas this question simply asks whether it is recommended to do so.

Comment: *Can anyone explain if there's a point to doing so?* – Well, from the voter’s egoistic point of view, there are all badges awarded for voting.

Comment: Downvotes on questions are free. There is however the daily limit, or the badges. Regarding downvoting a closed question, since the purpose of downvoting (At least how I see it) is to let the author know the poor quality of the question, or to let other readers (Who might think the question raises a good point) know this. If it was already closed, or suppose, has -5 rating, then I don't see the point. But as long as you don't reach the daily limit, I don't see why not.

Comment: The duplicate is not tagged as a feature request and the answers on the dupe are a perfect fit. I don't see anything new in your question that makes it necessary to do that discussion all over again

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180381/is-downvote-piling-really-necessary http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219669/reason-of-enabling-voting-after-the-question-gets-closed

Comment: @rene I partially agree, however the question to which you refer is already marked as a duplicate of another question (["The 'I Get It' Reputation Problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem)), which does not answer my question.

Comment: @chharvey you're free to disagree but I don't see why you keep referring to the dupe of the dupe. I didn't choose that one because it isn't a good fit. The one I choose has answers that address your concern. There is no rule that says that we need to close against a post that in itself is not a duplicate. Anyway, I see Monica provided a nice answer and random hammered this question against another duplicate. We all have what we want now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as noted in a comment, downvotes on questions are free.

Voting and closing are different actions -- granted, often with correlation, but they're not interchangable.  *Close* a question if it doesn't fit the site in its current form.  *Downvote* a question that is "unclear or not useful" (from the tooltip on the downvote button) or that shows no research effort.  Vote based on the content of the question, not its current open/closed status.

Is there a point?  Yes.  In addition to sending signal to readers (and the OP), your vote can feed the automatic processes that clean up abandoned and poor questions.  A downvoted closed question with no upvoted answers will be automatically deleted after some time.  It's long enough that if the author wants to fix the question he has a chance to do so, but if, as so often happens, the author never comes back to clarify the question, why keep it around?